# Adding dots between every char. What is the most Pythonic way?

Tags: python

I have some numbers as strings in the form of `'111'` or `'367'`. I want the output to be like `'1.1.1'` and `'3.6.7'`, respectively. I am thinking of doing this with a for loop to append each char in a list then join them with `'.'` I am just wondering is there a more *pythonic* way to achieve this ? or maybe a more pythonic way of splitting the string into a list ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>> '.'.join('111')
'1.1.1'
```

Yes, it's that simple. Here's the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) for `str.join`.

Comment: On a side note, if you want to keep the trailing and leading `.`s you can use `'111'.replace('', '.')`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> nums = ["3", "6", "7"]
>>> ".".join(nums)
"3.6.7"
```